# Printing select sheets from google sheet with Google Apps Script

Tags: printing, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible to write a GAS that will print the selected sheets in the code?

Example say I have multiple sheets but only want to print the sheets that have the word Map. So in the case below I would only want Map1, Map2, and Map3 printed. Is this possible or not?

- Master
- List
- Pivot Table
- Map1
- Map2
- Map3

Answer (score 0):

You can select the sheets and copy the content with AppsScript to another sheet and print it, can generate a HTML page with the content ready to print, but apps script can't show the dialog to print.

Comment: Would doing the copy keep all the formats, formulas, and conditional formats when pasting to the other page?